# thread local remove method

Tags: java, concurrency

Do you need to call remove on a thread local if you are not deploying in a server environment, even if the app uses a cached thread pool?

```
public static ThreadLocal<Integer> i = new ThreadLocal<Integer>(){{
    public Integer initialValue(){return 3;}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, if both the `Thread` and `ThreadLocal` are still in play, the value will be reachable. If either are unreachable, in theory, the value is garbage collectible if otherwise unreferenced. However, there is a bug in OpenJDK which means if the value references the `ThreadLocal` (surprisingly common) *and* the `Thread` is still running, it'll leak.

So yes, in a sense, there is nothing special about a server environment. However, generally where you are repeated reloading code during development then there it often the case that the `ThreadLocal` is reachable from the value (value to class-of-the-value to class-loader-of-the-class to all-classes-ever-loaded-through-class-loader to static-fields-of-those-classes to a `ThreadLocal`). Implementations of Java Beans and JDBC may have similar issues.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [javadoc for `ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html):

> ... after a thread goes away, all of its copies of thread-local instances are subject to garbage collection ...

If the thread may still be around, and you want the resource dereferenced, better call `remove()`.

Sounds like you might want to consider using a simple local variable if you want to clear it.

Comment: If you've got a cached thread pool, the threads may or may not be going away.